# NULL values in candidate keys

Tags: database, candidate-key

I'm wondering whether a attribute can have multiple NULL values and still be a candidate key.
Let's say we have a table with 3 columns, airport_id, airport_name, IATA_code.
Primary_key is a airport_id. IATA_code is not always provided for an airport but when it is, it uniquely identifies an airport. Can I therefore say that IATA_code is a candidate key (but can not be a primary key) and therefore there exist functional dependency between
IATA_code --> airport_id ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does an empty SQL table have a superkey? Does every SQL table have one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46024902/does-an-empty-sql-table-have-a-superkey-does-every-sql-table-have-one)

Comment: Is this about the relational model or SQL? The definitions of superkey & CK don't care what the values are. Just apply them. How are you stopped quoting them & applying them? What has your research shown? [ask] [Help] "Identifies", whatever it means, isn't part of those definitions. If you have "tables" that allow 2 copies of the same row because they have a null, that isn't a relation & the terms don't apply to that thing. On the other hand if you are using different definitions for the same terms in some other context, what is the context & the definitions?

Answer (score 0):

According to the definition of candidate key in relational database, you cannot say IATA_code is one of candidate keys.

Candidate key is the set of attributes by which it is possible to **identify** each row of the table. Therefore, if some attribute is nullable, it cannot be one of candidate keys.